# Open and manipulate several .tiff files from one folder using a loop in Python? Ensuring the files are imported as separate variables

Tags: python, gis, raster, tiff, rasterio

I have twenty .tif files which contain data from a globally mapped model. I am importing the files to python so I can rotate them, and make the .tif files Atlantic centered rather than Pacific centered. I can rotate individual files using the code below, however, I want to import all 20 files, rotate them all, and save them all in a new location using a loop rather than repeating the below lines of code for every single file.

TLDR: I need advice on how to loop the code below so can rotate 20 .tif files which are all in the same folder.

```
import rioxarray
rds_2000 = rioxarray.open_rasterio("path_to_tif")
rds_2000 = rds_2000.assign_coords(x=(((rds_2000.x + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('x')
rds_2000.rio.to_raster("path_to_newly_saved_tif)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this?

Assuming you write a function that captures the code you attached and returns the processed file

```
def process_function(filepath):
   do_something
   return processed_file
```

Then you can either created a `dict` or a `list`, if you want to access the files by filename or some other method dict is probably better.

```
files=os.listdir(files) #os some other method may be list comprehension
# alternative
# files=[file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith(".tiff")
processed={}
for file in files:
   processed[file]=process_function(file)
```

now you can access the data by going `processed[<filename>]`.

Hope that helps.